# I am getting this error in the console : Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined ı have no idea why ı am getting this error while I do check the code below everything seems fine :( trying to learn the way how react works :) 
So what is the purpose of this since all the properties I wrap on contextprovider suchas contacts loading and the functions I need

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import ContactContext from '../context/contactContext'

export default function ContactForm() {
  const name = useFormInput('')
  const email = useFormInput('')

  const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext)
  const { addContact } = contactContext

  const onSubmit = () => {
    addContact(name.value, email.value)
    name.onReset()
    email.onReset()
  }
  return (
   SOME HTML CODE HERE
  )
}

//contactState.js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import ContactContext from './contactContext'
import ContactReducer from './contactReducer'

const ContactState = props => {
  const initialState = {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: '098',
        name: 'Diana Prince',
        email: 'diana@us.army.mil'
      }
    ],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ContactReducer, initialState)
  const [contacts, loading] = state
  const addContact = (name, email) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
      payload: { id: _.uniqueId(10), name, email }
    })
  }
  const delContact = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'DEL_CONTACT',
      payload: id
    })
  }
  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider
      value={{
        contacts,
        loading,
        addContact,
        delContact
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default ContactState

//contactReducer.js
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTACT':
      return {
        contacts: [...state, action.payload]
      }
    case 'DEL_CONTACT':
      return {
        contacts: state.contacts.filter(
          contact => contact.id !== action.payload
        )
      }
    case 'START':
      return {
        loading: true
      }
    case 'COMPLETE':
      return {
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}

//contactContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react'
const contactContext = createContext()
export default contactContext
```

Comment: here is error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'addContact' of undefined

Comment: seems `contactContext` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer, when adding a contact, you're spreading the wrong state key. This should fix it:

```
case 'ADD_CONTACT':
  return {
    contacts: [...state.contacts, action.payload]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are using `ContactState` in your app. If you don't use it and render your `ContactForm` component with it then you can't reach any context value. You should render it as:

```
<ContactState>
  <ContactForm />
</ContactState>
```

in a suitable place in your app. Also, you can't get `contacts` and `loading` like that:

```
const [ contacts, loading ] = state;
```

`state` is not an array, it is an object here. You should use:

```
const { contacts, loading } = state
```

You can find a simplified version of your code below. I removed/changed some parts in order to run it as much as possible. You should fix your reducer as @Asaf David mentioned in their answer, but this is not the main problem here. After fixing the context issue, you can try to fix your reducer.

About your questions, if you try to understand how React works by looking at this example you can easily get confused. Because `Context` is an advanced concept (at least for the beginners). Also, the code uses `useReducer` with `Context` and this makes the things more complicated. If your intent is to understand the React itself then start with the [beginner guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html).

By using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) we can pass the data top-down to the deepest components. But, in order to use that data those components should be rendered as children of the context provider.

In your code, you are doing this in `ContactState` but you never use it. Also, in that component, you are defining a state with `useReducer` and feed your context with this state by `value`.

Finally, in your `ContactForm` component, you are using [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook to get the context data. In your current code since you don't render this component in a provider, `contactContext` is undefined and you are getting the error. You can't get `addContact` from undefined.

In my example, I'm retrieving the `contacts` to show something. Again, I've changed/removed some parts from your code.

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useReducer } = React;

const ContactContext = createContext();

function ContactForm() {
  // Changed those values
  const name = "";
  const email = "";

  const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext);
  // changed addContact -> contacts
  const { contacts } = contactContext;

  const onSubmit = () => {
    addContact(name.value, email.value);
    name.onReset();
    email.onReset();
  };
  // added some data to render
  return <div>{contacts[0].name}</div>;
}

function ContactReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CONTACT":
      return {
        contacts: [...state, action.payload]
      };
    case "DEL_CONTACT":
      return {
        contacts: state.contacts.filter(
          contact => contact.id !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case "START":
      return {
        loading: true
      };
    case "COMPLETE":
      return {
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const ContactState = props => {
  const initialState = {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: "098",
        name: "Diana Prince",
        email: "diana@us.army.mil"
      }
    ],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ContactReducer, initialState);
  const { contacts, loading } = state;
  const addContact = (name, email) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_CONTACT",
      // removed lodash part, added a static id
      payload: { id: 1, name, email }
    });
  };
  const delContact = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: "DEL_CONTACT",
      payload: id
    });
  };
  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider
      value={{
        contacts,
        loading,
        addContact,
        delContact
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  );
};

// added the relevant render part
ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactState>
    <ContactForm />
  </ContactState>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: serkan bey haklısınız array değil obje olarak yazdım yanlış yapmışım orada fakat yine çalıştıramadım

Comment: How do you render `ContactForm` now? PS: I'm using English, so everyone can get benefit from this conversation :)